# Заполнение массива рандомными значениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, случайные-числа

```
import random
import time
li = []
tmp = 100000
for i in range(0,100000):
    if tmp != 0:
        x1 = random.randint(0,tmp)
        li.append(x1)
        tmp = x1
    else: break
n = 1
start_time = time.clock()
while n < len(li):
     for i in range(len(li)-n):
          if li[i] > li[i+1]:
               li[i],li[i+1] = li[i+1],li[i]
     n += 1
print(li)
print ("{:g} seconds".format(time.clock() - start_time))
```

Нужно заполнить на 100.000 значений массив (и отсортировать пузырьком), вот только рандом немного хромает

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: Может быть, потому что вы поверх нормального рандома накрутили ещё какую-то малопонятную логику? Вы хотели неповторяющиеся значения или что? Если да, то это нужно явно указать в вопросе.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Заполнение случайными числами](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/90730beafd529755c7892515778bfe389d9e8f94/generate_random_list.py):

```
import random
items = [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(100000)]
print(len(items))  # 100000
```

---

Если нужны только уникальные числа в указанном диапазоне, тогда можно просто сгенерировать все числа из диапазона и перемешать их:

```
import random
items = list(range(100000))
print(items[:5])  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

random.shuffle(items)
print(items[:5])  # [718, 41458, 48336, 10501, 18877]
```

---

**jfs** предложил пример генерации случайных чисел используя модуль `numpy`:

```
import numpy
items = numpy.random.randint(100000, size=100000)
print(len(items), items[:5])  # 100000 [73846 49707 18846 73887 43349]
```

Эта функция сгенерирует указанное количество чисел, в указанном случайном диапазоне, но нет гарантии уникальности чисел.

---

**MaxU** предложил генерацию неповторяющихся случайных чисел используя `numpy.random.choice`:

```
import numpy
items = numpy.random.choice(100000, 100000, replace=False)
print(len(items), items[:5])  # 100000 [94792 79537  9678 66784 92049]
```

Comment: Уникальные числа можно сгенерировать так: np.random.choice(100000, 100000, replace=False)

Comment: можно `numpy.random.randint(100000, size=100000)`, чтобы диапазон совпадал c `range(100000)` (иначе `random_integers()` использует 1..100000 *включая границы* -- мне следовало сразу randint() вместо random_integers() предложить).¶ Если без повторений хотите, то `np.random.permutation(100000)` (аналогичен, приведённому choice() решению).

Comment: Да и `random_integers` вроде бы устарел и в описании метода как-раз рекомендуется использовать другой метод: `This function has been deprecated. Use randint instead.`

Comment: про "уникальность" у вас неточность. В `np.random.permutation(n)` числа не повторяются (случайная перестановка чисел в `[0, n)` диапазоне). В `np.random.randint(n, size=m)` числа могут повторяются (генерируется `m` случайных чисел из `[0, n)` диапазона с заменой) К примеру: `np.random.randint(2, size=5)` -> `array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0])`

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, уточнил. а так ниже писал про повторы